# php if is chekced get header redirect

Tags: php

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user clicks this button a header is sent, Below I have included the code for my button;

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

Here is the action I have that when the button is clicked I want to have performed.

```
header('Refresh: '.$duration.'; URL=http://youtubelives.com/'.$row[single_perm].'/'.$link.'/'.url_slug($unname, array('transliterate' => true)).''.$row[single_end].'');
```

Comment: I think you are mixing client-side actions with sever-side code.  You should either submit a form, or do it in JavaScript.

Comment: What is happening with this code?

Comment: i'm making "up next" function, so script is taking next video duration and redirection after this duration on next video page, so i want to give users access to enable or disable this...
see demo of button : http://mymus.ml/upnext.png